# Magento intercept coupon code logic?

Tags: php, magento

Trying super hard to understand Magento's code.

I need a way to intercept coupon codes to prevent them working if an item in the cart is already discounted.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

This can be achieved by using an observer, subscribing to the `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_couponPost` event.

Or by overriding the Cart controller.  Specifically, the `couponPostAction` method

Comment: Thanks, how were you able to know where to look?  For me it seems like guess work, just searching all files for the word 'coupon' and hoping something looks obvious.  Is there some documentation you are using?  Do you have a special tool helping you or did you keep guessing overtime until you eventually built some knowledge through trial and error?

Also is it better that I learn the Zend framework first?

Comment: @LucasScholten - over time, you will know where to look for things.  Also, think what is involved in applying a coupon: you are posting data to a controller.  So there will always be a predispatch event fired + actions to override *if absolutely necessary*

Comment: Thanks for asking.  I've been able to intercept the point at which a coupon is submitted in the function you suggested.  I simply wrote `die('you entered a coupon');` to test.  I now want to be able to see what items are in the cart and whether any are discounted.  How can I pull this information?  Is there any way I can dump all the data relating to the products in cart, it would be useful to know for future projects.

Comment: Which method did you go for - observer or controller override?

Comment: At the moment I am literally editing the CartController.php file directly.  Once I have a basic understanding I hope to be move the code to a separate module with observer.